ERROR CARGA DE REGISTROS DE UN NUEVO CAMPO JAVA - ANDROID STUDIO
tengo una situación en que quiero agregar un nuevo campo a mi tabla de la base local de la aplicación, la cual se carga una vez iniciada la sesión con datos consultados al servidor, el problema que surge es que cuando intento acceder a ese nuevo campo me dice que No value for tipo, en este caso la columna se llama tipo, el JSON no incluye el campo por lo tanto me marca error al intentar acceder a el.
Mi metodo para obtener los datos de la base de datos.
private function getProductosAsign($idPromotor){
    $sql = "SELECT P.idProducto, P.nombre, P.presentacion, P.idMarca, P.codigoBarras, P.tester, 
            IF(pp.precio_compra IS NULL,0.0,pp.precio_compra) AS precio_compra , 
            IF(pp.precio_sugerido_venta IS NULL, 0.0, pp.precio_sugerido_venta) AS precio_sugerido_venta, P.tipo, P.descripcion, 
            pp.update as precio_update
  
            FROM Producto AS P 
            RIGHT JOIN marcaAsignadaPromotor AS mA ON P.idMarca=mA.idMarca
            LEFT JOIN producto_precio AS pp ON pp.idProducto=P.idProducto 
            WHERE P.estatus='1' AND mA.idPromotor=".$idPromotor;

    $db = DataBase::getInstance();
    return $db->ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}

Mi metodo para generar un Array, esto se encuentra en un archivo llamado marca.php
Posteriormente se instancia en otro php llamado serv.php, se incluye el marca.php y se invoca su function de esta manera.
public function getProductosById($idPromo){

    $response = $this->getProductosAsign($idPromo);
    $array = array();

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
        array_push($array, array('idProducto'=>$fila['idProducto'],
            'nombre'=> $fila['nombre'] , 'presentacion' => $fila['presentacion'], 'idMarca'=>$fila['idMarca'],
            'cb'=>$fila['codigoBarras'], 'tester'=> $fila['tester'], 'precio_compra'=>$fila['precio_compra'],
            'precio_sugerido'=> $fila['precio_sugerido_venta'], 'precio_update'=>$fila['precio_update'],
            'descripcion'=> $fila['descripcion'], 'tipo' => $fila['tipo']));
    }

    return $array;

}


$marcas = new marcas();
        $client = new clientes();
        $rutas = new rutaVisita();
        $materiales = new Materiales();

        $response['marca'] = $marcas->getMarcasByID($id);
        $response['producto'] = $marcas->getProductosById($id);
        $response['exhibiciones'] = $marcas->getExhibicionesById($id);
        $response['tiendas'] = $client->getTiendasByID($id);
        $response['ruta'] = $rutas->getRutaByID($id);
        $response['productoformato'] = $marcas->getProductosByFormato($id);
        $response['productotienda'] = $marcas->getProductosByTienda($id);
        $response['materiales'] = $materiales->getMaterialesJson();
        $response['categoriasProductos'] = $marcas->getCateProd();


        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        echo json_encode(array('idPromotor'=> $id , 'marcas'=>$response['marca'],
            'productos'=>$response['producto'], 'exhibiciones' => $response['exhibiciones'],
            'tiendas' => $response['tiendas'], 'ruta' => $response['ruta'],
            'productoFormato' => $response['productoformato'],
            'productoTienda' => $response['productotienda'],
            'materiales'=> $response['materiales'],
            'categoriasProductos' => $response['categoriasProductos']),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Ahora supongo que ahí se debe de generar el JSON con ese nuevo campo llamado tipo, ahora vamos a manejar esa respuesta.
    @Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, final JSONObject response) {


    Log.v("OnSuccess Info", "1");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    if (response != null){


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                try {
                    JSONArray marcas = response.getJSONArray("marcas");
                    JSONArray productos = response.getJSONArray("productos");
                    JSONArray exhibiciones = response.getJSONArray("exhibiciones");
                    JSONArray tiendas = response.getJSONArray("tiendas");
                    JSONArray ruta = response.getJSONArray("ruta");
                    JSONArray productoFormato = response.getJSONArray("productoFormato");
                    JSONArray productoTienda = response.getJSONArray("productoTienda");
                    JSONArray materiales = response.getJSONArray("materiales");
                    JSONArray tiendaMarca = response.getJSONArray("tienda_marca");
                    JSONArray categoriasProductos = response.getJSONArray("categoriasProductos");

                    Log.v("INFOCAT", String.valueOf(categoriasProductos.length()));
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de marcas: " + marcas.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de productos: " + productos.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de exhibiciones: " + exhibiciones.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de tiendas: " + tiendas.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de ruta: " + ruta.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de productoFormato: " + productoFormato.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de productoTienda: " + productoTienda.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de materiales: " + materiales.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de tiendaMarca: " + tiendaMarca.toString());
                    Log.d("INFOCAT", "Contenido de categoriasProductos: " + categoriasProductos.toString());

                    parseJSONMarca(marcas);
                    parseJSONProductos(productos);
                    parseJSONExhi(exhibiciones);
                    parseJsonTiendas(tiendas);
                    parseJSONRuta(ruta);
                    parseJSONProductoByFormato(productoFormato);
                    parseJSONProductoByTienda(productoTienda);
                    parseJSONMateriales(materiales);
                    parseJSONCategoriasProd(categoriasProductos);


                    insertTiendaMarca(tiendaMarca);

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            progressDialog.setMessage("Sincronización completa");

                        }
                    });




                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    }, 1500);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("NOTINFOCAT", "Error");


                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Ocurrio un problema al guardar la informacion, intentelo mas tarde");
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, 4000);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Ocurrio un problema al guardar la informacion, intentelo mas tarde");
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, 4000);
                }


            }
        }).start();



    }



}

Y tengo este metodo que considero que itera ese JSON para cargarlo a la base de datos local
    private synchronized void parseJSONProductos(JSONArray productosArray) throws JSONException {
    BDopenHelper b = new BDopenHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    Configuracion configuracion = new Configuracion(context);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String fecha = dFecha.format(c.getTime());

    b.deleteTable("producto");

    for(int i= 0; i < productosArray.length(); i++) {

        b.insertarProducto(productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idProducto"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("presentacion"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("idMarca"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cb"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("tester"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("precio_compra"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("precio_sugerido"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("precio_update"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tipo"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("has_image"),
                productosArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("agotado")
        );




    }


    configuracion.setProducto(fecha);
}



Haz una depuración del objeto productosArray, revisando cómo está estructurado y qué tiene dentro. Bastaría con poner un punto de interrupción en la línea que sigue a la definición del método parseJSONProductos().
